# Finding the Unit Tangent vector to the following Function.

Tags: calculus, vectors

I have the following vector valued function:
$$\vec{r}(t)= \begin{bmatrix}\vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}f(t) \\ g(t) \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
I have to calculate the unit tangent vector which I presume would be as follows:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}(t)= \begin{bmatrix} \vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} f'(t) \\ g'(t)\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

The formula for unit tangent vector is given as follows:
$$\vec{T}(t) = \frac{\vec{r'}(t)}{||\vec{r'}(t)||}$$

Substituting in what I have from my $\vec{r'}(t)$ I get the following:

$$\vec{T}(t) = \frac{\begin{bmatrix} \vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  f'(t) \\ g'(t)\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}}{\sqrt{(f'(t)^2) +(g'(t))^2+(0)^2}}$$
This would be my final answer right due in part with some simplifications.  is this the right method to calculate the Unit Tangent Vector.

Comment: What is that $ijk$ thing supposed to mean? Besides that (and assuming that both $f$ and $g$ are continuously differentiable) your method looks good to me.

Comment: Your answer is correct. As an aside, I've never seen someone prefer that notation over just saying $f(t) \hat{i} + g(t) \hat{j}$ or even $<f(t),g(t),0>$.

Comment: @zugzug my thought would be somebody later on in the site might say that the matrix \begin{bmatrix} f'(t) \\ g'(t) \\ h'(t) \end{bmatrix} is the vector that is being norm is being calculated for.